# Restrict SQL Login on a MS SQL Database based on Host Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication

We are trying to restrict SQL Type Login on a MS SQL Database based on Host Name. The IP addresses for these host names are dynamic. I am able to print the current logged in user using the below query.

I tried looking around but was not able to locate much info. Do we have feasibility to restrict SQL Type Login based on the host names. Thanks in advance

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) as [DB]
, login_name
, nt_domain
, nt_user_name
, status
, host_name
, program_name
, COUNT(*) AS [Connections] FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE database_id > 0 
and login_name='MySQLLogin' 
GROUP BY database_id, login_name, status, host_name, program_name, nt_domain, nt_user_name;
```

Comment: The only way I can think of is creating sort of a "control server". There you create a DB and a table with the configuration you want, and Linked servers to all the servers yo want to control. Then you use an remote call to a SP which inside uses [sp_configure].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [Logon Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) which fire after the authentication phase but before the user session gets established, e.g.:

```sql
USE master;  
GO
CREATE TRIGGER host_name_reject_trigger
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON  
AS
BEGIN
    IF HOST_NAME() in (N'bad_host', N'worse_host', N'the_worst')
        ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Someone connecting from bad_host, worse_host or the_worst in this example will receive an error message similar to the following:

```
Logon failed for login 'sa' due to trigger execution.
Changed database context to 'master'.
Changed language setting to us_english. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 17892)
```

Of course this relies on `HOST_NAME()` returning what you would term a "correct" result. The [HOST_NAME (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/host-name-transact-sql) specifically says:

> ***Important***
>
> *The client application provides the workstation name and can provide inaccurate data. Do not rely upon HOST_NAME as a security feature.*

You should try to find some mechanism other than `HOST_NAME()` to identify logins that should be rejected.